# Navigation bar doesn't appear after login

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller that checks a condition and goes to a login view controller. But when login viewcontroller returns, my view controller's navigation bar does not appear after that. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  [   NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IRANSansMobile", size: 16)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
    navigationItem.title = contact

    if user.Status == -1{
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TOLOGIN", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: What is the kind of this segue? If it is `show`, you will see the navigation bar. If it is `present`, there will be not navigation controller (it is like a full screen dialog box that must be released to see what was on before)

Comment: The type of segue is Show . @user9335240

Comment: You present other view controller just inside viewDidLoad? Did you have some other unexpected behavior?

Comment: Is there a UINavigationController as a parent for your view? This must be done from storyboard, try to embed the viewcontroller in a Navigation Controller.    If your UI is programmatic, you should create a UINavigationController, then make your viewcontroller as root of this

Comment: no other problems I have...I put check login in other function after view didload but the problem was same.after returning to my viewcontrolller navigation bar disappear

Comment: @user9335240 I added a navigationcontroller to this viewcontroller but problem not solved .

Comment: Not add the navigation to the viewcontroller, it is the reverse. Instead of doing `window.rootViewController = LoginViewController()`, try to do `window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())`. Not the opposite

Comment: i solved the problem by present instead of  push   viewcontroller @user9335240